# Cannot access data property of Axios response object after successful GET request: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm building a personal project with React and TypeScript to learn the ropes, and I'm stuck with a strange (to me) error on the following block, where I use Axios to fetch some data:

```
const fetchItem = async () => {
  const response = await axios
    .get("http://localhost:4000/items?id=2")
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  console.log(response.data);
};
```

The error message is `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'` and pops up immediately on Visual Studio Code as soon as I try to access the `data` property of my `response` object.

How can I access `response.data` correctly (without having both my IDE and Webpack complaining)?

Here is the full code of my component, for reference:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { css } from "emotion";
import axios from "axios";

import { Item } from "./Item/Item";

export interface ContentProps {
  view: string;
}

const fetchItem = async () => {
  const response = await axios
    .get("http://localhost:4000/items?id=2")
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  console.log(response.data);
};

export class Content extends React.Component<ContentProps> {
  state = {
    text: "test"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchItem();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.view === "item" ? (
          <Item text={this.state.text} />
        ) : (
          <List />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The error on webpack:

[image]

The full error text on VSC's tooltip states: `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void | AxiosResponse<any>'.`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `await`, when erroring out returns `undefined`, since `console.log` in your `catch` returns `undefined`, and the return value is inferred as `void`.

Basically here you are mixing async/await sync style with promise async style of writing async code, it's better to stick to one to avoid confusion like here with good'ol `try catch`.

So it can go like this:

```
const fetchItem = async() => {
  try {
    const response = await axios("http://localhost:4000/items?id=2");
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Would comment, but can't yet...

The inner `catch` can return a possible `void`. If you remove that/handle it different then at least TS doesn't complain.